# Navigation Draw Submenu Array Error

Tags: android, arrays

I'm trying to add an item from array to navigation draw submenu. But i could not it. My code ise here

```
> private void addItemsRunTime(NavigationView navigationView) {

    //adding items run time
    final Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        menu.add("Runtime item "+ i);
    }

    //stringArray[0]="Selam";
    //stringArray[1]="Merhaba";
    //stringArray[2]="Merhaba";
    //stringArray[3]="Merhaba";

    // adding a section and items into it
    final SubMenu subMenu = menu.addSubMenu("SubMenu Title");
    for (int i = 0; i <= sayaca; i++) {
        subMenu.add("SubMenu Item " + i);
    }

    // refreshing navigation drawer adapter
    for (int i = 0, count = mNavigationView.getChildCount(); i < count; i++) {
        final View child = mNavigationView.getChildAt(i);
        if (child != null && child instanceof ListView) {
            final ListView menuView = (ListView) child;
            final HeaderViewListAdapter adapter = (HeaderViewListAdapter) menuView.getAdapter();
            final BaseAdapter wrapped = (BaseAdapter) adapter.getWrappedAdapter();
            wrapped.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

when i change my code like this "for (int i = 0; i <= myArray.length; i++)" it gives me and error.and my application is closed. Message is here.

[image]

Array is working other function. But in this now working.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

it throws exception to your `myarray.length`  try to saving it in a variable then use the variable.

Comment: int index = myArray.length;
for (int i = 0; i <= index-1; i++)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong thing , you must loopthrough from 0 to n-1 values and then your error will be solved because last element of array is always at (n-1)th location , so just make change like ,

```
for (int i = 0; i <= myArray.length-1; i++)
```

Comment: for navigation drawer projects i suggest to use these https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer